# If I send money to someone on student visa in USA, will he need to pay taxes on that?

Tags: united-states, taxes

If I sell a website and send the money directly (from buyer, who is also located in USA) to a friend in USA who is on student VISA there, will he need to pay taxes on that amount? Is it legal for his VISA status? I want this so I can use that money when I go there and can avoid the currency conversion charges and avoid hassles.

Comment: The simplest answer is "maybe"... the flag for raising interest from the IRS is about $10K total... meaning $9,999 USD twice would still flag interest.  If your website is selling for more than that, perhaps you can engage a tax advisor to inform you.

Comment: The total sell money is around $12k. So should I not do this?

Answer (score 2):

First: *I am not a tax lawyer. This is just an educated opinion; not a legally verified answer.*

Taxes are to be paid on *income*, not on money that you handle for someone. So if the idea is only that he gets and holds the money for you until a later point in time, there should be no tax liability.
If the amount is high enough to raise a flag in the bank so the IRS might look at it, and he wants to be sure to not get in trouble, he should keep it separate, and keep a record of 'handing it to you'. Note that *if* he makes interest on it, or uses it to pay his credit down until you come or such, the situation changes.

Answer (score -1):

If i am not wrong, any business activities such should be declared on Year End Tax filing. If your friend is going to own that website either it is commercial or nonprofit, he has to declare in the year end taxation.

Comment: not the website, the *money* is supposed to go to that student.